# Flutter Provider: proper way to split notifying

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm trying to split firing update of widgets with `Provider`.
I'm using latest `Flutter` version. Within app I'm also using `context.select()`, `context.watch()` and `context.read()`.

Now to the main goal. What exactly I'm talking about. So I have some notifier:

```
class ExpenseNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Category> _selectedCategories = [];
  Expense _currentExpense;
  int _removeId;
  Expense _editExpense;
}
```

Now, `ExpenseNotifier` has a few consumers. All consumers will be updated when something will change. Except one case: when `_editExpense` updated only one consumer should be updated. Thing is that the class `Expense` already exists in the notifier, so all consumers connected to `_currentExpense` also reacts on `_editExpense` update...

I'm now using selectors. Like this:

```
context.select<ExpenseNotifier, Expense>((notifier) => notifier.currentExpense);
```

But looks like widget also reacts on `_editExpense` updates for some reason...

What is the proper solution for that situation? Is it possible (without defining new type) achieve it within `ExpenseNotifier`?

Probably, something like this should work:

```
class EditExpense {
  final Expense expense;
  EditExpense(this.expense);
}
```

So in this case wrapper class is needed. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: probably the easiest solution would be to make some of the Consumers just ignore the editExpense field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your question interesting , so I thought it would be worth working on it . I am giving a sort of general answer but I think you will be benefited from it.

First add methods to data class which will update only the required fields ,
like this :

```
class DataClass with ChangeNotifier {
  String firstString = " ";
  String secondString = " ";

  void updateFirst(String newString) {
    firstString = newString;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updateSecond(String newString) {
    secondString = newString;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Now it's time to refactor , you have to make two classes(or methods) that will have their own build methods (you can also define two methods and pass the `BuildContext` to them):

```
class StringOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("StringOne build method is called");
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          children: [
            Text(context.select((DataClass value) => value.firstString)),
            Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              child: TextField(
                onChanged: (text) {
                  context.read<DataClass>().updateFirst(text);
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And

```
class StringTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("StringTwo build method is called");
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          children: [
            Text(context.select((DataClass value) => value.secondString)),
            Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              child: TextField(
                onChanged: (text) {
                  context.read<DataClass>().updateSecond(text);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Finally have these classes in other class which describes the UI:

```
class ProviderExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [StringOne(), StringTwo()],
    );
  }
}
```

you might say it will increase verbosity , actually ,  refactoring often makes the code more verbose but it also makes code clearer and easy to maintain. In your case it will also prevent unnecessary builds.

`Console :`

```
I/flutter ( 1469): StringTwo build method is called
I/flutter ( 1469): StringTwo build method is called
I/flutter ( 1469): StringTwo build method is called
I/flutter ( 1469): StringTwo build method is called
I/zygote64( 1469): Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB
I/flutter ( 1469): StringOne build method is called
I/chatty  ( 1469): uid=10140(com.example.stack_overflow) 1.ui identical 7 lines
I/flutter ( 1469): StringOne build method is called
I/flutter ( 1469): StringOne build method is called
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply! :) I think I have something like this and for me it isn't work. Mean that both widget updates

Comment: well , if you have done something similar to this ,then only one build should be called at a time . Might able to help you if you share more code.